# TFS 2015 keeps removing custom build steps

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines, custom-build-step

For some reason, my on-premise TFS 2015 (update3) keeps removing the custom made build steps from build definitions when clicked on Edit Build Definition.

I Then need to click 'undo' to restore the removed custom build step.

Does anyone know why TFS is doing this? And also, is there any fix for this weird behaviour?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with update 3. Did this behavior also occurs with your new crated build definition? Try to add your custom build step in a new created build definition and then edit it for test.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT I've just confirmed that it also happens for newly created build definitions in TFS 15.3

Comment: Did you install the custom task by extension or not? You can follow this article to add a custom build task: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task

Comment: How do you install the custom task? By extension or tfx cli? Can you try to delete the build task from server and then re-add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there was a minor configuration error in the `task.json` file. The person who made the build task had `Deploy` as the value of the `visibility` property, where only `Build` and/or `Release` are valid values.

I think this property somehow got mixed up with the `category` property - which is the build task category tab it belongs to - whereas visibility defines if the task is a valid build task for Build configurations and/or Release configurations.